# How to make Spring (Hibernate) instantiate child entities in single table inheritance scenario as their proxies instead of base entity proxy?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Recently I started getting Hibernate's `HHH000179: Narrowing proxy to class` warning when attempting to delete child entites (inheritance) that contain other relations.

This led me to learning that Hibernate proxies are created for each entity separately, even if such entity is an abstract base entity (not `@MappedSuperclass`, but just `abstract @Entity`) - that is even if base entity class will never exist on its own.

Consider structure of attributes:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(...)
public abstract class Attribute { ...ids and common fields... }

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("V")
public class AttributeValued extends Attribute
{
    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "attribute",
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
                orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Value> values = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}
```

With Spring JPA i have repository such as:

```
interface AttributeRepository extends JpaRepository<Attribute, Long> {}
```

Consider given some id that is known to be of type `AttributeValued` I run this:

```
Attribute a = this.attributeRepository.getReferenceById(id);
if (a instanceof AttributeValued)
{
    System.out.println("VALUED");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("OTHER");
}
```

This prints 'OTHER' while I'd expect it to print VALUED.
That means that Spring/Hibernate instantiated `#getReferenceById` to base class `Attribute` (or rather it's Hibernate proxy).

***Is there a way for Spring/Hibernate to return proxy of actual entity (`AttributeValued`) when using common `JpaRepository<Attribute>`?***

Because of this behivior if I do something like this:

```
// id is known to be of type AttributeValued
Attribute a = this.attributeRepository.getReferenceById(id);
this.attributeRepository.delete(a);
```

Hibernate will strike me with `HHH000179: Narrowing proxy to class AttributeValued` because variable `a` is proxy of `Attribute` while `delete(a)` will create another representation of the same row as proxy of `AttributeValued`, because of `AttributeValued.values` relation having:

```
cascade = CascadeType.ALL
orphanRemoval = true
```

So now I have proxy of `Attribute` and proxy of `AttributeValued` (I think).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so problem was absolutely elsewhere than I thought.

`#getReferenceById` is `JpaRepository` method.

which I used basically everywhere in my whole project (since Hibernate is Jpa and I assumed it's the correct way).

Turns out that querying with it is for some reason not polymorphic and returns proxy of `Attribute`, even if row is known to represent `AttributeValued` (with `@DiscriminatorValue("V")`).

`#findById(id)` is a `CrudRepository` method and it actually is polymorphic and returns proxy of `AttributeValued`, thus when I use `#delete(id)` later, I will not get problems like in original question (two proxies for the same row and warning `HHH000179: Narrowing proxy to class`).

Comment: Yes, this is particularly nasty coming from an old project where one has been using explicitly defined JPA repository interfaces, as switching to getReferenceById attempts to directly instantiate potentially abstract classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Embedded annotation on Child entity so that child and parent entities will form a single table in database
You can read more about this in official documentation https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-embedded-embeddable

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant for this scenario. Question is rather why query returns instance of Attribute, even if it's known to be AttributeValue, and how would I force it to return correct type based on @DiscriminatorValue?